# Pydantic use alias and initial name of a field interchangeably

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic, pydantic-v2

If I create a Pydantic model with a field having an alias, I would like to be allowed to use the initial name or the alias interchangeably. This is possible when creating an object (thanks to `populate_by_name=True`), but not when using the object.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, Field


class Resource(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(alias="identifier")
    model_config = ConfigDict(populate_by_name=True)


r1 = Resource(name="a name")  # works
r2 = Resource(identifier="a name")  # works thanks to populate_by_name=True

print(r1.name)  # works
print(r2.identifier)  # AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'identifier'
```

Is this at all possible, and if yes, how?

The alternative would be to have a `@computed_field` (`identifier`) which would just return the attribute `name` and no alias. This is less clean semantically.

Comment: Interesting question! I have an idea to use model_validator to implement this. I'm going to try it tomorrow

Comment: An aliased field's name and alias shouldn't be used interchangeably not only when accessing the field but also in the constructor. Note that mypy or pyright raises an error on `Resource(name="a name")`. This is due to the fact that `BaseModel` is defined as a [`dataclass_transform`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0681/). Defining an alias in `Field` changes the `__init__` definition produced.

Comment: @PawełRubin Thanks for the info and pointers. What I would like looks tricky indeed. I might have been misleaded by the name `alias`.